# PHP/MySQL Selecionar produtos abaixo de um valor na tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso selecionar os produtos com o valor abaixo de 300 reais no qual a coluna `situacao` seja igual a `2`:

Exemplo: na tabela compras eu tenho 8 produtos cadastrado:

```
1 sapato valor 25 situacao 1    
2 calça valor 50 situacao 2    
3 meia valor 60 situacao 2    
4 sandália valor 70 situacao 1    
5 bicicleta valor 120 situacao 2    
6 pc core 2 duo valor 250 situacao 2    
7 notebook valor 500 situacao 2    
8 ipad 8 gb valor 600 situacao 2
```

Eu tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valor, MAX($valor) FROM ofertas WHERE situacao = '2'") or print (mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT valor,FROM ofertas WHERE  MAX($valor) AND situacao = '2'") or print (mysql_error());
```

Sendo que eu preciso que seja feito no formato acima ou o mais simples possível.

Comment: Tente essa query: `SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE situacao=2 AND valor < 300 ORDER BY valor ASC` ou seja, seleciona todos os valores abaixo de 300 cuja a situação seja igual a "2" e ordena pela coluna "valor".

Comment: Tome cuidado com seus títulos, pois o seu não reflete o conteúdo da pergunta, pois vc não quer selecionar o valor máximo, e sim produtos abaixo de um valor

Comment: Olá La Souza. Veja [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), assim será mais fácil ajudá-lo.

Comment: No último exemplo em **$query = mysql_query("SELECT valor,FROM ofertas WHERE MAX($valor) AND situacao = '2'") or print (mysql_error());**, está correreto a vírgula em **valor, FROM**?

Comment: Essa era a maneira errada de se fazer, que eu postei só pra mostrar como eu estava fazendo errado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Então, para pegar os valores abaixo de 300 reais, basta apenas fazer isso:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE valor < 300 AND outrasCondicoes...;
```

Para pegar com o maior valor:

```
SELECT max(valor) FROM tabela WHERE outrasCondicoes...
```

Para pegar o maior valor, abaixo dos 300 reais:

```
SELECT max(valor) FROM tabela WHERE valor < 300 AND outrasCondicoes...
```

Seria isso?

Answer (score 0):

> Preciso selecionar os produtos com o valor abaixo de 300 reais no qual
>   a coluna situacao seja igual a 2:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE situacao LIKE '2' AND valor < 300") or print (mysql_error());
```

Isso deduzindo que seu código está correto neste ponto e a situação está em formato de texto, caso não, ao invés de usar `LIKE '2'` vc deve utilizar apenas `= 2`, ficando assim:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE situacao = 2 AND valor < 300") or print (mysql_error());
```

O mesmo serve para o `300`, caso este esteja em formato de texto vc deverá utilizar `LIKE '300'`